# Do I need to lock before read a shared variable?

Tags: c, linux

I'm totally new to multiple processes/threads programming in C, i understand that if one process needs to modify a shared variable, it needs to lock before doing so.

If one process needs to read a shared variable, does it need to lock ?

Comment: How is the variable shared if only one process needs it?

Comment: A concrete use case would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

If that variable can be changed by another thread or process, then yes.  If you have a lot of reading processes/threads, you may consider implementing a read-write lock that allows many readers to access at once.

Depending on what exactly you are doing, you may also want to look into atomics as they do not require the use of locks.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic

Comment: I don’t know why you were downvoted, this is the correct answer with extra suggestions. I’m getting really tired of this snob attitude at SO.

Comment: my use case is, many read, little write, looks like read-write lock suits my needs

Comment: sorry, I don't think it is a correct answer, reader are not always need to set lock , if there is only 1 writer and 1 reader ,and if the write operation is atomic , I think you do not need to lock in reader.

Comment: @peter__barnes The number of readers/writers is irrelevant.  Even one of each can cause race-conditions in which you read an incorrect.  As for the case of atomic operations, that is covered in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes . if one variables is shared between multiple process ,u need to do so, as it avoids the errors in Ur result, i.e one process wants to do read/write/modify on the shared variable/data he needs to check is that variable is free or not ,then he need to proceed.if its free then lock it and do process on it or else it has to wait till it free